# How to get ordered list of strings

Tags: python, list

I have a list looking like this:

```
pages= ['page34','page1','page12','page9','page11','page2','page10']
```

I have tested this:

```
pages.sorted()
```

and I got something "almost" ordered, but not ok:

```
>>> pages
['page1', 'page10', 'page11', 'page12', 'page2', 'page34', 'page9']
```

So, How could I get the desired ordered list, looking like:

page1, page2, page9, page10, page11, page12 and page34

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that as:

```
pages = ['page34','page1','page12','page9','page11','page2','page10']

pages.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[4:]))

>>> print pages
['page1', 'page2', 'page9', 'page10', 'page11', 'page12', 'page34']
```

This will sort the list based on the ***numeric*** value of the page number (`x[4:]`)

Suggested reading (by Grijesh Chauhan): https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: Very good one, THANKS, it worked. I didn' t know that you can do sort like that. Thanks.

Comment: @user2919052, No problem. Glad to have helped.

Comment: @user2919052 you should always read manual of function from Python doc.

Comment: @user2919052 read https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: Thanks, Grijesh, I will for sure!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Nice link. I have incorporated into my answer. Thank you!